# Initializing ExpressionTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython

i have a given code:

```
import wx

from application.gui.ctrls.panelCalibration.PanelGridCalibration import PanelGridCalibration
from lib.common.dataStructures.Value import ExpressionValue


class PanelValueCalibration(PanelGridCalibration):
    def __init__(self, parent, defaultValues, changeableSize=False):
        PanelGridCalibration.__init__(self, parent, defaultValues, False)
        self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
        self.grid.SetColLabelSize(0)
        self.grid.SetDimension(1, 1)
        self.grid.Unbind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_CLICK)
        wx.CallAfter(self.ExpandCell)

        self.DisableWriteByVariable()

    def ExpandCell(self):
        self.grid.SetColSize(0, self.grid.GetClientSize().x - 20)

    def SetDefaultValues(self, defaultValue):
        pass
        #self.grid.GetTable().SetDefaultValue(0, 0, defaultValue)

    def SetValues(self, value):
        self.grid.GetTable().SetValue(0, 0, value.GetValue())

    def OnGridDimensionChanged(self, oldDimension, newDimension):
        pass

    def GetValues(self):
        return ExpressionValue(self.grid.GetCellValue(0, 0))

    def CheckInput(self):
        if self.GetValues().GetValue() == None:
            self.ShowErrorDialog(_(u"Kein Wert zum Schreiben angegeben!"))
            return False
        return True
```

as you see, `PanelValueCalibration` inherits from `PanelGridCalibration`. However, I want to modify `PanelValueCalibration` to use a `TextCtrl` instead of a `GridCtrl`. I see there is an `ExpressionTextCtrl` class but I don't know how to import it into my `PanelValueCalibration` class.

edit:
I already inserted:

```
from application.gui.ctrls.ExpressionCtrls import ExpressionTextCtrl
```

but don't know how to define the `init` correctly:

```
class PanelValueCalibration(ExpressionTextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, defaultValues, changeableSize=False):
        ExpressionTextCtrl.__init__(self, parent, defaultValues, False)
```

Comment: Are you sure `ExpressionTextCtrl` is a wxPython class? I can't find any documentation for it at all. I'm also not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want there to be only a single `TextCtrl` or do you want many `TextCtrl`s in a grid?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I just started learning python, and as an exercise I have to do little changes in a huge given code. So I don't even know which word in this code is a Python class and which is a defined function. I thought "ExpressionTextCtrl" is something similar to "PanelGridCalibration" so that I just can replace it =) And there shall be only one single TextCtrl.

Comment: I think `ExpressionTextCtrl` and `PanelValueCalibration` are classes that you define in your application, not built-in classes. It's impossible for us to help you without seeing the code for those classes too. For now, I think you should search Google  for some wxPython tutorials ([here's the #1 result](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/)) and familiarize yourself with the basic operations. Then try to look at your application's code and understand it.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a control that's part of wxPython.